# How/can this type be made into a Monoid instance

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, monoids

I have data type:

```
data Stuff s = Stuff { name :: s, idx :: Int }
```

And want to make this into a monoid w/ the following implementations:

```
tmappend :: Stuff s -> Stuff t -> Stuff (s,t) 
tmappend s1 s2 = Stuff (name s1, name s2) (idx s1 + idx s2)

tzero :: Stuff ()
tzero =  Stuff () 0
```

Note it's possible to get arbitrarily nested tuples through `mconcat`.

But tmappend is currently violating the type signature of `mappend`. Is this actually a monoid? Can it be made into one with a better type representation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is known as a lax monoidal functor.  I highly recommend you read [this paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) which shows how Applicatives are one type of lax monoid and you can reformulate your type as an `Applicative` and get an equivalent interface:

```
instance Applicative Stuff where
    pure a = Stuff a 0
    (Stuff f m) <*> (Stuff x n) = Stuff (f x) (m + n)

tmappend :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
tmappend fa fb = (,) <$> fa <*> fb

tzero :: (Applicative f) => f ()
tzero = pure ()
```

Notice that `tmappend` and `tzero` work for all `Applicative`s, not just `Stuff`.  The paper I linked discusses this idiom in more detail.

Comment: I don't know what a "lax monoid" is, and think you mean "lax monoidal functor."

Comment: Yes, I meant lax monoidal functor.  I'll fix it.

Comment: This `Applicative`, incidentally, can be built up from [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor-Product.html), [`Constant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor-Constant.html), [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor-Identity.html) and [`Sum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum): `type Stuff a = Product (Constant (Sum Int)) Identity a`.